# Is there any way to count spesific dates from the same column?

Tags: sql, looker-studio

```
Date                             status
2020-08-07 20:18:41 UTC          created 
2020-08-10 20:18:41 UTC          phase 1    #spent 3 days in phase 1
2020-08-13 20:18:41 UTC          phase 2    #spent 3 days in phase 2
```

Is there any way to count specific dates days from the same column?, I would like to have the number of days in each phase

Comment: Do statuses have a specific next status they transition to? Are they in another table (they should be). Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution, or something for Google Data Studio? If you mean SQL, then please tag your question with the database you are running: maybe google-big-query?

Comment: I'm building a DataSDataStudio Dashboard But using BigQuery as data warehouse, thanks for asking and the answer, have a good one

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery you can use something like this:

```
select timestamp_diff(lag(date) over (order by date), date, day) as dur
```

I'm not sure if you want `lag()` or `lead()`, though.  The sample data suggests `lag()`.  The problem suggests `lead()`.